# HTML/CSS, i created a website with a navigation bar but for some reason wont work when i click submenu links

Tags: css, html

HTML/CSS, i created a website with a navigation bar but for some reason when i click the submenu links, some work and some dont. For example on my page if you hover over input, it gives you 3 dropdowns and if you click "add business" and then click "add category" it wont work(it won't redirect you to the "add category pg")

Here is the link to the website:http://output.jsbin.com/rebokab

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--
    Created using JS Bin
    http://jsbin.com

    Copyright (c) 2017 by njp98 (http://jsbin.com/rebokab/25/edit)

    Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
    -->
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Homepage</title>

    <style id="jsbin-css">
    body {
    background-color: White;
    }


    .intro-header{
    background-image: 
    url('http://www.corporatelivewire.com/images/deals/1320/2021321577.jpg')

    }


    .site-heading{
    color:white; 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:copperplate;
    text-align: center;

    }




    .subheading{
    color:white;
    font-size:30px; 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:copperplate;
    text-align:center;
    }


    .Course{
    text-align: center;
    }

    .PD{
    text-align: center;
    }

    .ERD{
    text-align: center;
    }

    .LINKS{
    text-align: center;
    }

    p{
    font-weight:bold;
    }
    .container{
    text-align: center;
    }

    .navigation {
    background: blue;
    }

    .navigation ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    }

    .navigation ul a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative; /* optional but safe */
}

.navigation ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}

.navigation ul li:hover a {
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navigation ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  display: none;
}

.navigation ul ul li {
  float: none;  /* optional but safe */
  width: 250px;
}

.navigation ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.navigation ul ul ul {
  display:none;
  left: 100%;
  background: #333;
  top: 0
}

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {

  .navigation ul li {
    float: none;
  }

  .navigation ul ul {
    z-index: 1
  }

  .navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 25%;
    top: 100%;
    /* width: 200px; */
  }

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- Navigation -->
   <nav class="row navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://output.jsbin.com/rebokab">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="">Input</a>

              <ul>
                <li>
                <a href="http://output.jsbin.com/salizoc">Add Business</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="http://output.jsbin.com/zevejok">Add Category</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a href="http://output.jsbin.com/gijumus">Add Transaction</a>
                </li>               
             </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Output</a>
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Output 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">output 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Output 3</a></li>

         </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>



<!-- Page Header -->
    <!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
    <header class="intro-header">
        <div class="container">
        `enter code here`    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="site-heading">
                        <h1>Database Technologies</h1>
                        <hr class="small">
                      <span class="subheading">Expense Database</span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </header>


  <div class="Course">
  <h1>Course Information</h1>
  <p>Database Technologies</p>
  <p>Semester: Spring 2017</p>
  <h3>Group Information</h3>
  <p>Nish Patel, Netid: njp98</p>
  <p>Jason Ma, Netid: jcm322 </p>
  <p>Jonathan, Chandy Netid: jc1518</p>
  </div>

  <div class="PD">
  <h2>Project Description</h2>

  <p>
    Creating an Expense Database to allow an individuals 
     to track their consumer purchasing history in a manner 
     that reports may be generated and analysis may be performed.
  </p>
  </div>   


  <div class="ERD">          
  <h2>ERD Diagram</h2>
  <p>Click on the link to view ERD diagram,
    <a href="http://i66.tinypic.com/t54mqs.jpg">ERD Diagram</a>

    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="LINKS">
    <h2>Description of Links</h2>
    <h3>Input</h3>
    <p>The input page will allow users to add a business transaction. For example users may eneter a businesses information, such as name,address,phone number,
       etc. also what type of store is it(food,retail,gas,etc.)</p>
    <h3>Output</h3>
    <p>The output page will allow users to search for a certain business or category of businesses. Also will allow user to search for customer information.</p>
    <h3>Mix</h3>
    <p>This page is a mix of both input and outpages in which users can enter information into the databse and also get results of the database.</p>
  </div>

<footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; Database Technologies 2017</p>
                    <p class="copyright text-muted">Nish Patel | Jason Ma | Jonathan Chandy</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>    

<script src="http://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js?3.41.10"></script>
<script>jsbinShowEdit && jsbinShowEdit({"static":"http://static.jsbin.com","root":"http://jsbin.com"});</script>
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-1656750-34', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's because on your second page, you haven't added actual links - just an empty hash. Check here: http://jsbin.com/zevejok/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
<li><a href="#">Add Business</a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="http://output.jsbin.com/salizoc">Add Business</a></li>
```

and the other links like this...

```css
body {
    background-color: White;
    }


    .intro-header{
    background-image: 
    url('http://www.corporatelivewire.com/images/deals/1320/2021321577.jpg')

    }


    .site-heading{
    color:white; 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:copperplate;
    text-align: center;

    }




    .subheading{
    color:white;
    font-size:30px; 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:copperplate;
    text-align:center;
    }


    .Course{
    text-align: center;
    }

    .PD{
    text-align: center;
    }

    .ERD{
    text-align: center;
    }

    .LINKS{
    text-align: center;
    }

    p{
    font-weight:bold;
    }
    .container{
    text-align: center;
    }

    .navigation {
    background: blue;
    }

    .navigation ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    }

    .navigation ul a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative; /* optional but safe */
}

.navigation ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}

.navigation ul li:hover a {
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navigation ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  display: none;
}

.navigation ul ul li {
  float: none;  /* optional but safe */
  width: 250px;
}

.navigation ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.navigation ul ul ul {
  display:none;
  left: 100%;
  background: #333;
  top: 0
}

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {

  .navigation ul li {
    float: none;
  }

  .navigation ul ul {
    z-index: 1
  }

  .navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 25%;
    top: 100%;
    /* width: 200px; */
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--
    Created using JS Bin
    http://jsbin.com

    Copyright (c) 2017 by njp98 (http://jsbin.com/rebokab/25/edit)

    Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
    -->
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- Navigation -->
   <nav class="row navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://output.jsbin.com/rebokab">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="">Input</a>

              <ul>
                <li>
                <a href="http://output.jsbin.com/salizoc">Add Business</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="http://output.jsbin.com/zevejok">Add Category</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a href="http://output.jsbin.com/gijumus">Add Transaction</a>
                </li>               
             </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Output</a>
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Output 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">output 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Output 3</a></li>

         </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>



<!-- Page Header -->
    <!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
    <header class="intro-header">
        <div class="container">
        `enter code here`    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="site-heading">
                        <h1>Database Technologies</h1>
                        <hr class="small">
                      <span class="subheading">Expense Database</span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </header>


  <div class="Course">
  <h1>Course Information</h1>
  <p>Database Technologies</p>
  <p>Semester: Spring 2017</p>
  <h3>Group Information</h3>
  <p>Nish Patel, Netid: njp98</p>
  <p>Jason Ma, Netid: jcm322 </p>
  <p>Jonathan, Chandy Netid: jc1518</p>
  </div>

  <div class="PD">
  <h2>Project Description</h2>

  <p>
    Creating an Expense Database to allow an individuals 
     to track their consumer purchasing history in a manner 
     that reports may be generated and analysis may be performed.
  </p>
  </div>   


  <div class="ERD">          
  <h2>ERD Diagram</h2>
  <p>Click on the link to view ERD diagram,
    <a href="http://i66.tinypic.com/t54mqs.jpg">ERD Diagram</a>

    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="LINKS">
    <h2>Description of Links</h2>
    <h3>Input</h3>
    <p>The input page will allow users to add a business transaction. For example users may eneter a businesses information, such as name,address,phone number,
       etc. also what type of store is it(food,retail,gas,etc.)</p>
    <h3>Output</h3>
    <p>The output page will allow users to search for a certain business or category of businesses. Also will allow user to search for customer information.</p>
    <h3>Mix</h3>
    <p>This page is a mix of both input and outpages in which users can enter information into the databse and also get results of the database.</p>
  </div>

<footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; Database Technologies 2017</p>
                    <p class="copyright text-muted">Nish Patel | Jason Ma | Jonathan Chandy</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>    

<script src="http://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js?3.41.10"></script>
<script>jsbinShowEdit && jsbinShowEdit({"static":"http://static.jsbin.com","root":"http://jsbin.com"});</script>
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-1656750-34', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your website.. Its working.. but problem is that.. your add_category page and add_business page links are not properly set. From your home page every page is accessible, but from other pages its not accessing, so make sure on other pages you added proper links to every other page your are redirecting from there.